# Running html QUnit tests as part of TFS build gives an error about start() outside of test context

Tags: qunit, chutzpah

Using the [instructions here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04aug15/nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-vnext-build/), I'm trying to configure QUnit tests through chutzpah

[image: error]

The error is:

```
Error: Error: Error: Called start() outside of a test context while already started
at start in https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.18.0/qunit.min.js (line 11)
at startQUnit (line 12)
at onPageLoaded (line 16)
```

And the test is formatted like:

```
module('Product - Somme Condition', {
    setup: function () {
        $('#Markup').append('<div>...</div>');
    },
    teardown: function () {
        $('#Markup').empty();
    }
});

test('Given When Then', function () {
  //..
});
```

With the HTML runner being set up like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Test Runner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.18.0/qunit.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.18.0/qunit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blanket.js/1.1.4/blanket.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../BuildFiles/someDependency.js"></script>
    <script src="../../BuildFiles/product.js"></script>
    <script src="../Tests/Product/ProductTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="qunit"></div>
        <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
        <div id="Markup"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The step is set up as a Visual Studio Test step:

[image: test step]

<sub>(I will change it to *.html once working, it's just easier to test on one, all files behave the same and are structured as above)</sub>

**The tests show up in the log as "Passed", but the build step is inconclusive. How can I make this green?**

[image: build steps]

**-- EDIT**

Using the [example QUnit test](https://qunitjs.com/),

Namely,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.2.1.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And calling chutzpah via:

```
chutzpah.console.exe C:\Dev_Scratch\testRunner.html
```

The error output is:

> Chutzpah console test runner  (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000) Version
>   4.3.4.0 Copyright (C) 2016 Matthew Manela (http://matthewmanela.com).
>
> **Error: Error: Called start() while test already started running at**
>   **start in https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.2.1.js (line 2550) at**
>   **startQUnit  (line 12) at onPageLoaded  (line 16)  (line 18) While**
>   **Running:C:\Dev_Scratch\testRunner.html**
>
> **Error: Error: Called start() while test already started running While**
>   **Running:C:\Dev_Scratch\testRunner.html**
>
> File: C:\Dev_Scratch\testRunner.html
>        1 total, 0 failed, took 0.01 seconds
>
> Tests complete: 1
>   === 1 total, 0 failed, took 2.52 seconds ===

Comment: Does this work when you are running locally using the chutzpah.console.exe application?

Comment: @MatthewManela when running from chutzpah.console.exe I get the same error. Opening the html file in a browser is ok tho.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in option in the build definition which could change the status.

Yellow with a ✓ stands for partially pass.

If you want to change the status of build to green. As a workaround, you could use a batch file to run your test. Then you just need to [Redirecting Error Messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout). This will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that sounds like a reasonable alternative... but I'd rather configure the QUnit tests or chutzpah to not throw the error in the first place :-)